# В WebStorm введенное название тега не оборачивается автоматически скобками

Tags: html, webstorm

Столкнулся с тем, что WebStorm перестал оборачивать набираемые HTML-теги угловыми скобками и не подставляет автоматически закрывающий тег. Покопался в настройках, но так и не нашел, как вернуть этот базовый функционал.

Ввожу начало название тега -> появляется список автоподстановки -> выбираю нужный мне тип элемента -> название добавляется, но после нажатия на "Tab" слово не оборачивается в <угловые скобки>.

Обнаружил только что, что и Emmet перестал работать. Синтакс div.nav>ul>li*5>a не срабатывает. Хотя в CSS-файлах вроде как предлагает эмметовские сокращения и поддерживает их.

Comment: Спасибо, описание подправил. Вот бы еще кто нибудь помог саму проблему решить. ))

Comment: Попробуйте обратиться в техподдержку

Comment: Обратился, но не получил от них пока достойного решения.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки: "Settings" > "Editor" > "Emmet" - включён ли сам Emmet, нужная ли клавиша выбрана для раскрытия сокращений. Также см. https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/enabling-emmet-support.html

Comment: Проверил, там всё в порядке. Опция "Enable XML/HTML Emmet" включена.